# Conditional probablity , how should I continue from here? (attempt added)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given that a family have $n$  childern for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is in the probability $$C\cdot\left({\frac{9}{17}}\right)^n$$ for $C>0$. the probability for getting male or female is equal.

**What is the probablity  that there is $7$ childrens in  the family given that there is no females**

**My attempt**

First of all I found $C$ in the following way:
$$P(\mathbb{N})=1=\large\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}C\cdot\left({\frac{9}{17}}\right)^n$$
$$C=\frac{8}{17}$$

Let $A$ and $B$ be an events :

$A$ - there is 7 childrens in the familiy

$B$ - there is no females in the familiy

I want to calculate $$P(A|B)$$
for this I want use the formula $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
now calculate $P(B)$ is easy it is $\frac{1}{2}$

Now how should I calculate $P(A\cap B)$? is it true to argue that $A$ and $B$ are independent and than use the formula $$P(A\cap B)= P(A) \cdot P(B)?$$
not sure how should I do this step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(B)$ is not $\frac{1}{2}$, that would be the probability of one of the children being male or female, but from what you said I think $B$ is the event where none of the children are female (so all of them are male). You need to consider how many children are (and you cannot say 7 because $B$ has nothing to do with $A$ in $P(B)$).

If you call $C_i$ for $i=0,1,2,\ldots$ the event that there are $i$ children, then $P(B)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P(B\mid C_i)P(C_i)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2}^i\frac{8}{17}\frac{9}{17}^i=\frac{8}{17}\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{2}\frac{9}{17})^i=\ldots$

Note that I substituted $P(B\mid C_i)=\frac{1}{2}^i$, since that's the probability of having no females given that there are $i$ children. From that summation you get $P(B)$.

Now, for the rest, you just need one more step:

$P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\dfrac{P(B\mid A)P(A)}{P(B)}$

Note $A=C_7$.

Comment: Ok I understood your attiude. there is one thing I did not get, in $P(B)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P(B\mid C_i)P(C_i)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2}^i\frac{8}{17}\frac{9}{17}^i=\frac{8}{17}\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{2}\frac{9}{17})^i=\ldots$ why we sum up to infinty and not up to 7?

Comment: Becuase $B$ has nothing to do with $A$ itself. $B$ is the event where no child is female, and that event alone doesn't give you information about how many children are there (we relate $A$ and $B$ with $A\mid B$ later), so when considering $P(B)$ you have to consider all cases separately. This is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).